# Why do i get a TypeError in this code of python?

Tags: python

I want to get each item in the list 'spam' but i an not able to call spam list..

```
spam = ['apples' , 'bananas' , 'tofu' , 'cats']
i = 0
n = len(spam)


for i in range (0, n):
    if i <= n :
        print(spam(i) , end = ',')
        i += 1
    else:
        break
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\commaCode.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(spam(i) , end = ',')
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Did you try to convert a `while` loop to a `for` loop? You seem to have missed some crucial parts of a `for` loop with `range`.  You don't need the `if`, you don't need to increment `i` manually and you don't need `break`. In fact, you don't even need the `i`. Please read the answer of @tyrion below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message points out, *list objects are not callable*.
You should access the items of your list with square brackets (i.e. `spam[i]` instead of `spam(i)`).

Also, when iterating on a list, you can avoid using range most of the time:

```
spam = ['apples' , 'bananas' , 'tofu' , 'cats']

for thing in spam:
    print(thing , end = ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

List slicing in python works like this `spam[i]`, using normal brackets on something always means "calling" it, meaning treating it like a function to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is with this line:

```py
print(spam(i) , end = ',')
```

In this instance, since you've encased `i` within rounded brackets, Python attempts to execute `spam()` as a Function while passing `i` as an argument. To fix this, use square brackets instead:

```py
print(spam[i] , end = ',')
```